# How Twitter API method HOME Time Line works?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-feed

I try to get tweets from user's home using home method.

http://api.twitter.com/version/statuses/home_timeline.format

If I use paging and set as the following..

Example.

paging.setSinceId(000009L);

What would be the expected result returned from API ?

in my home, there will be like following tweets.

---

000050( The most recent one)

....

000040

000039

.....

000023

000022

000021

000020

......

000013

000012

000011

000010

......

000003

000002

000001

---

Actually, I should receive Tweets ( 000010 to 000020 ) . right?

but, when I called the API, it seems like the returned result is ( 000030 to 000050).

Is it the correct way of working API ? or do I miss something?

If I want to get Tweets ( 000010 to 000020 ) , how can I do it?

PS: I use Twitter4j Lib.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits to how far back you can go in your timeline.

From the API docs
"This method is can only return up to 800 statuses, including retweets."
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline

So, if you have have more than 800 tweets you can only expect to be able to get the most recent 800.

Secondly, the id's of tweets are not just their numerical order in your timeline. Every tweet is assigned a globally unique id across all users. This is the id that is expected  by the API I believe.

Comment: @computermacgyver...oh I use sequential number to Tweets because I just want to portray the flow of getting the correct tweets (maybe by the created time or whatever.. ). API Doc says I can get 800 status, but I only get 200 in max. :(  I just want to confirm that API return for  **it seems like the returned result is ( 000030 to 000050).** according to my question with other twitter developer. Thanks.